# Image from URL is not showing in emulator for android in react native

Tags: android, react-native, image

I have added simple image in the application but it is not showing in android emulator, I am able to see image in real android device and also in iOS simulator. I have tried various types of image and I am able to access all the formate unless url.

```
  <Image resizeMode="cover" 
        source={{ uri: 'https://www.pngfind.com/pngs/m/666-6668401_man-with-laptop-computer-how-can-i-assess.png' }} 
        style={{ width: 140, height: 140}} />
```

This is the code for it.

I have tried with changing and removing resizeMode and height, width but none of them where useful. I have also tried with .jpg image in url but the result is the same. I have also added

```
 bundleInDebug: true
```

this to app/build.gradle and also added

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

this to android manifest. I have killed and reset the metro multiple times but it also didn't helped. I need to make image visible in android emulator.

Comment: try open your url image on emulator browser if it not showing then it problem from emulator connection

Comment: @MochamadTaufikHidayat Thanks for suggestion, I have checked for that and found out that the internet on device is not working. So I have added DNS.